# Unable to delete record in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, routes, sql-delete

I am trying to delete a record but unable to reach delete function in controller. Everything seems to be fine.

Tried with resource controller `destroy` function and also with custom route. But form is not posting to controller instead it's refreshing showing token and method in URL.

Previously, I was using Javascript function to confirm delete but it was also not working. So I switched to direct post.

Here is the Javascript code which was not submitting saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

But, `console.log(id)` gives me correct id.

Even I am using this Javascript function everywhere in site but on this page it is not working.

```
function confirmDeleteUserCartItem(id)
{
  let choice = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Item ?")
  if (choice)
  {
    document.getElementById('delete-usercart-item-' + id).submit();
  }
}
```

View: Tried with 2 routes

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.cart.delete', $item->id) }}">
 @csrf  
 @method('DELETE')
  <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('user.cart.destroy', $item->id)}}">
  @csrf  
  @method('DELETE')
 <button type="submit" class="remove">
  <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
 </button>
 </form>
```

This is what I am getting in URL after clicking delete:

```
?_token=klYTBg3OBr0oLfTeS9tSGJwBepgLX8wtCsKRgMOR&_method=DELETE
```

Comment: how is your web.php route file looking like?

Comment: Weird thing is happening. I am able to delete records which are added later after first record. But first record is not getting deleted, only page redirects and token is shown in url.
Even if first record is another item after clearing the cart.

Comment: Can you check if you can retrieve a model of the specific record by using the ::find(); method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works. I hope if your `route` and controller `destroy` method is okay then it should work -

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('user.cart.destroy', $item->id)}}" 
                           onsubmit="return confirmDeleteUserCartItem()">
   @csrf  
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="remove">
       <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
   </button>
 </form>
```

And you javascript method -

```
<script>
  function confirmDeleteUserCartItem()
  {

     let choice = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Item ?")
     if (choice)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.
There was an another form tag in the html template which I was using in view.
It was stopping the delete form to get submitted.